# Full Weather Station with Raspberry Pi 3 the hard questions writing it with Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to establish a weather station with a Raspberry Pi 3
the code will be written in Python
the Raspberry Pi will be connected directly with an Adafruit DHT-22 Sensor
a BMP-180 Sensor and a DS18B20 Sensor
the remote station will use an ESP-8266
and also the Raspberry Pi will be taking measurements from the Open Weather Maps
there's going to be a GUI and also the measurements will be displayed on Thinkspeak (for the IOT part)
My problem now
I want to display all the measurements from the sensors but also I want to display the difference from the ESP-8266 Sensor and the Open Weather Maps

#something like this#
"the difference in temperature from the station and the satellite is ..."
#or#
"the measurements are equal"

is there a way to create a command in Python that does just that
because Pycharm wasn't happy with my code ...

```
import Adafruit_DHT
import pyowm

DHT22Sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
DHTpin = 16

humidity_indoors, temperature_indoors = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(DHT22Sensor, DHTpin)

degree_sign = u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'
owm = pyowm.OWM('')
observation = owm.weather_at_place('Larissa, GR')
weather_sat = observation.get_weather()
status_sat = weather.get_detailed_status()
temperature_sat = weather.get_temperature('celsius')['temp']
wind_sat = weather.get_wind('miles_hour')['speed']
humidity_sat = weather.get_humidity()

def mphtokmh(wind):
    kmh = (float)(wind * 1.60)
    return kmh

if humidity_indoors is not None and temperature_indoors is not None :
    print('Temp={0:0.1 f} * C Humidity={1:0.1 f}%' .format(temperature_indoors, humitity_indoors))
else :
    print('Failed to get reading, Try Again!')

print("The Sky is...{}".format(status_sat))
print("the temperature in our town is...{}C".format(temperature_sat))
print("the windspeed is...{}Km/h".format(wind_sat))
print("humid is...{}"%.format(humitity_sat))

if temperature_sat==temperature_indoors
    print("No Difference to show")

if temperature_sat>temperature_indoors
    print(temperature_sat)

if temperature_sat<temperature_indoors
    print(temperature_indoors)
```

(ps this is just a test code)

Comment: what is the error you're getting? "pycharm wasn't happy" isn't terribly descriptive

Comment: SyntaxError on line 22

Comment: if temperature_sat==temperature_indoors
    print("No Difference to show")

if temperature_sat>temperature_indoors
    print(temperature_sat)

if temperature_sat<temperature_indoors
    print(temperature_indoors)

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly what you mean from the comments, because line 22 of your example does not match your second comment, but you are definitely missing semicolons for those `if` statements. You'll have another problem eventually with the `mphtokmh` function by improperly using `float`. Python is a dynamically typed language, and you don't have to specify that you want a float. Also the extra parenthesis around `float` will create another problem, and you should just get rid of it: `kmh = wind * 1.60`

Comment: I'm in Greece and we are using Km/h

Comment: But OpenWeatherMaps only gives me Miles/h for the windspeed and I have to convert the miles given by the Satellite to Km/h

Comment: Answer me this...Can I save the data to an external file and then run another code to compare the data (yes ???)....And how can I call all of them to the GUI ???...Isn't it a little too much for the Raspberry Pi ???

Comment: I'm saying `kmh = (float)(wind * 1.60)` is wrong, and `kmh = wind * 1.60` is the correct way to do it... "How do I make a GUI?" is a little too broad a question for a single post, and the raspberry pi has plenty of power to do all this and more.